# Easier way to Populate Jstree with 6 levels

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, jstree

I have been working since last week with jstree for a project, and right now I am kind of stuck. I have been able to make it work with static data, but now I need to do it dynamically, and it needs to have up to 6 levels nested. Another condition is that the user should be able to just choose the deepest level, so I need to disable and make invisible the checkbox whenever a node has a children.

I am getting the data from SQL, but I am using a software called Thingworx to generate the user interface of the project (the tree is going to be a widget of for this software), so using JSON I think it's not an option.

My problem is that the only solution that I have found for now is something like this:

```
out:
var rowsActualData = core.data.rows.length
for (var i = 0, i < rowsActualData, i++){
    if (Level1Value === core.data[i].text){
        var rowsActualData2 = core.data.children.rows.length
        for (var j = 0, j < rowsActualData2, j++){
            if (Level2Value === core.data[i].children[j].text){
                if (Level3Value !== null){
                    var rowsActualData3 = core.data.children.children.rows.length
...
```

[All the levels of the code. Need less indent to be able to show it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQg0t.jpg)

To check each case I need to check if the node exist already, go to the next level and check if exist, several times. And then, depending on each condition, I need to write it down as a new one or push it to one that exists already (for each level).

[Part of the code for the first row, when the tree doesn't have data yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpcJP.jpg)

Here an example of how it should look, but populating it with static data https://jsfiddle.net/josuenanin/LeyeLsrc/3/

Maybe I haven't explained myself too well, but not sure how to explain it without a lot of code.

Thank you in advance.